# Trouble loading wordnet package in R

Tags: r, wordnet

I have trouble loading wordnet into R. I use R x64 2.14.1. I installed the package wordnet and then I tried to load the package.

```
> library(wordnet)
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
```

What is wrong? How and to what should I set the directory WNHOME.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the dictionary path. See example below.

```
setDict("/Users/kasper2304/Desktop/WordNet-3.0/dict")
```

Further I had problems using R-studio so I was forced to use JGR.

Answer (score 4):

The data has to be installed separately. 
If you are on Linux, just install the "wordnet" package (on Windows, it will be more manual).

```
sudo apt-get install wordnet  # For Debian-based distributions
```

Answer (score 3):

This works fine. We need to set WNHOME to dict's parent directory which is ./WordNet/2.1 from R using Sys.setenv()

```
library(wordnet)
setDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
Sys.setenv(WNHOME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it by downloading and installing wordnet from http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/2.1/WordNet-2.1.exe
and then rerunning

```
library(wordnet)
setDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while calling the library "wordnet" in R on Windows.
Then after many unsuccessful trials,I downloaded the WordNet_2.1.exe file from this site https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/users-choice/Wordnet_2.1.html.
After downloading this,you can directly set path in R and proceed with no further interuptions. For me this worked:

```
    library(wordnet)
    setDict("C:/Program Files/WordNet/2.1/dict")
    Sys.setenv(WNHOME = "C:/Program Files/WordNet/2.1")
    getDict()
```

Try it!!